# Print initial layer only on outside of print

Tags: 3d-models, ultimaker-cura, fusion360

I am using Ultimaker Cura to print what are essentially cookie cutters - a thin wall that is a silhouette of the shape. I would like to have a broader surface for the top. In Ultimaker Cura, I set it to print a wider "initial layer" but this initial layer is printed both inside and outside the print. Is there a setting I can use to print the initial layer outside the print? I am using Fusion 360 to create the model and would like to avoid having to build this separate layer for every model I build, unless it can be done fairly easily as these shapes will vary for each model.

As an additional question, what would be the best way to split an image into individual pieces - one for the outline of the whole shape and individual pieces for each distinct part of the image, say eyes, nose, mouth - that you would use to build the image after you cut out the pieces? I've tried using InkScape but I am not able to get it to divide them into clean pieces.

Comment: Does Cura have a setting for "brim"? Because a brim is usually only applied to the outside.

Comment: @Davo - Yes it does and I was thinking the same thing. The only thing which may not be optimal is the single layer of it not being very strong (only one layer deep). I don't *believe* there's a way to get multiple brim layers to make it a bit more robust. It is, after all, made to just peal off of the print. I don't think it would stand up to any long term use.

Comment: It is best to design the piece as you want it - brim is too flimsy for this usage.

Comment: While a standard brim might be too flimsy, you could manually edit the gcode and replace the first 10 layers with layer 1.

Comment: @PerplexedDipole - I think that's what the OP was trying to get away from in the first place ... ie: editing every print prior to printing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 "Unless it can be done fairly easily" but I guess that is subjective.

Comment: Not helpful since it's Cura, but this would be trivial with S3D and two processes for the file.
Simply set the "lower" process to only one perimeter, with "outline direction" set to "outside-in", and enable "merge outlines into a single solid model" if it isn't already.

Comment: Thanks everyone I think I’m leaning towards building the brim into the project. As an experiment, I inserted the svg file twice. The brim is a slightly larger scaled version I extruded to 2mm then added the smaller extruded version on top of it. That seems to do the trick. I just need to find a good way to get images separated into individual components for the second half of my original question.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just build two copies of the (flat) shape, shrink one by 10% and take the Boolean Difference to create your 'top'  ?

Comment: Carl, that’s essentially what I did. It works in most cases. I only run into issues if it’s a fairly complex shape. In those instances, curves and inside corners don’t always line up, but it’s usually good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to getting the brim set up was to select the area for each individual piece (in GIMP), then duplicate that selection and "grow" it to make it larger to create the lip. From there, I extruded the larger section a few millimeters and extruded the smaller selection on top of that and hollowed it out. Still working on the exact measurements to achieve the lip width and height, but the process is in place.